# C# Simple interest calculator switch error

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, switch-statement, calc

I am trying to make a simple interest calculator wherein a person enters a number (1 - 4) for what they want to calculate, then enter the given numbers and get the missing variable.

code:

```
using System;
using System.Convert;

public class InterestCalculator {
    static public void Main(string [] args) {
        int final, initial, rate, time, input;

        Console.WriteLine("What do you want to calculate? \n 1. Final amount after interest. \n 2. Initial amount after interest. \n 3. Interest rate. \n 4. Time passed");
        input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        switch (input){
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the initial amount.");
                initial = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the interest rate.");
                rate = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the time passed.");
                time = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                final = initial * rate * time;
                Console.WriteLine("$" + final + " is the final amount after interest.");
                break;
            case 2:
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the final amount.");
                final = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the interest rate.");
                rate = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the time passed.");
                time = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine);
                initial = final/(rate * time);
                Console.WriteLine("$" + initial + " is the initial amount before interest.");
                break;
            case 3:
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the final amount.");
                final = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the initial amount.");
                initial = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the time passed.");
                time = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine);
                rate = final/(initial * time);
                Console.WriteLine("%" + initial + " per time cycle is the interest rate");
                break;
            case 4:
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the final amount.");
                final = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the initial amount.");
                initial = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine);
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the interest rate.");
                rate = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                time = final/(initial * rate);
                Console.WriteLine(initial + " cycles is the amount of time passed.");
                break;}
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid input.");
        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting this error in the compilation process (using mono):

```
error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for System.Convert.ToInt32(bool) has some invalid arguments
error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `method group' expression to type `bool'
error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `System.Convert.ToInt32(bool)' has some invalid arguments
error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `method group' expression to type `bool'
error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `System.Convert.ToInt32(bool)' has some invalid arguments
error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `method group' expression to type `bool'
```

Comment: in your code, in every case chamnge the:
initial = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine);
to initial = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

and do the same with "time"

Comment: I'd also advise you not to use the word 'final' as the name of a variable, just for good practice (because it's a keyword).

Lastly, Never directly try to convert a users's input to an integer. The app will crash if you fill in a non-numeric value.

Comment: @Tarske While I agree with you on not using keywords as identifiers I see nothing wrong with using final here as it is not a keyword in C#

Comment: @ThomasSchremser Oops, you are right. Apologies, and thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well one of your `Console.ReadLine()` doesn't have brackets. So you're passing the method rather than calling it.

Comment: I've counted three thus far.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the places you only have

> Console.ReadLine instead of Console.ReadLine()

Check in code. For example -

Case 2

```
time = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine);
```

Correct all these lines.

Also, suggested to get input first into local variable and then try to convert.